# Is there a HP DeskJet 5940 maintenance tool for Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, cleaning

According to HP, the printer is not yet supported on Windows 7, so this could well be the answer. The printer is supported by Microsoft's drivers, but as far as I can tell, this is just a basic driver with no frills.

I need to clean and align my ink cartridges because the quality right now is terrible. I've tried installing the Vista x64 drivers, but the setup detects that I'm not running Vista and does not allow me to continue.

I was hoping there is a hack for this, or something similar. If not, I'll just plug it into my Vista laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it isn't fully supported, you can either run it inside a virtual machine such as [XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) or [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org) and install the driver through there (If printer is a network one, it will be easy... If the printer is USB, you have to enable USB Pass-through).

However, Just looked up a picture of the printer - are you sure there isn't a way to manually do this? It is usually achieved by holding down a button.

Comment: Just tried fiddling with them... It seems that the two with ink drops aren't buttons. The only buttons are "cancel" and "retry".